# writeAsVectorFormat creates .GPKG instead of .SHP

Tags: qgis, shapefile, pyqgis

I am trying to create a shapefile from the existing layer. Sadly I get a .GPKG file instead of .SHP file. How to correct this?

QGIS - 3.0.1

Here is the code:

```
from qgis.core import *
import qgis.utils


_layer = QgsVectorLayer("C:/Arundhati/RadioSignal/MasterLine.shp", "MASTERLINE", "ogr")

if not _layer.isValid():
  print("Layer failed to load!")

else:
    print("Layer was loaded successfully!")

_writer = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(_layer,"C:/Arundhati/RadioSignal/MasterLine12.shp",'utf-8')
```

Comment: Set driver to "ESRI Shapefile" https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/src/core/qgsvectorfilewriter.cpp. GeoPackage is the default format in QGIS 3. That's not sad at all but you can override the default if you wish.

Comment: embrace GPKG and forgett SHP sadness forever :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GeoPackage is the default format in QGIS 3 but you can override the default if you wish. Set driver to "ESRI Shapefile.